# CDI @ApplicationScoped vs @RequestScoped and factory pattern

Tags: cdi, factory

It is better to create an application scoped factory or should it be request scoped when using factory pattern to create objects?

Application scoped beans are created once but uses memory space. Request scoped beans are created for each call but using memory space only at lifetime. Request scoped beans could created multiple times.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeObjectFactory {
   public SomeObject createObject() {
      // do some stuff
   }
}
```

Are there any best practices?

Answer (score 4):

I think you won't find a very definitive answer for this question. The reason is that it really depends on your application:

- Should the bean exist only during the lifespan of a request? If so, use [`@RequestScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html).
- Should the bean exist during the lifespan of the application and should the state of the bean be shared between all the requests? If so, use [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is no need to share one instance of a factory, I think.  Is there any problem to create tons of application scoped beans?

Comment: @LarsMichaelis You can have many producer methods in the same class, so it'll reduce the amount of classes. However, more important than the scope of the class that contains the producer methods is the scope of the beans being produced.